# Extract any numbers before first occurrence of letter in string

Tags: php

I have street address strings (e.g., 123 Lincoln St., 2453 Park Ave).

I'd like to extract the street number for each string, i.e. any numeral characters that appear before letters in each address.

Comment: What about 123-a?   Do you want first letters or first space?

Comment: What about when you have 123 3rd Ave?

Answer (score 0):

Like this will work:

```
$streetNumber = preg_replace("/^([^ ]+)/i","$1",$streetAddress);
```

This will get out anything before the first space.

```
"123 Lincoln St." => "123"
"2453 Park Ave"   => "2453"
"123-a 1st St."   => "123-a"
```

If you want a real integer, use:

```
$streetNumberInteger = intval($streetAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the street number and the name will be separated by a space, you can try

```
    $array = explode(' ', $streetAddress);
    $number = $array[0];
```

$array[0] will always give you the first part of the string, before the first space.